# python Data schema for interconnected data

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to think about this problem but I think it's a data schema-related problem. My usecase is a fairly complex so here's a simple example.

Imagine I have a app where people have debt($100 in this example) and they are going to pay it back until get gets to 0. I made a example of this below:

```
from datetime import date
current_debt = 100
year_to_zero = 10
current_year = date.today().year
netzero_year = current_year + year_to_zero
yearly_reduction = year_to_zero/current_debt * current_debt
processed_year_left = year_to_zero
loop_current_debt = current_debt
while processed_year_left != 0:
  loop_current_year = netzero_year - processed_year_left
  loop_current_debt = loop_current_debt - yearly_reduction
  netzero_year - processed_year_left
  amount_reduced = yearly_reduction

  print("current year - ", loop_current_year, " current debt - ", loop_current_debt, "reduced by ", amount_reduced)
  
  processed_year_left = processed_year_left -1
```

Where I'm not sure what to do is this code assumes the reduction is done evenly. What if one year the person wants to reduce their debt by 20 instead of 10, how do I store that?

Also if I want to use this data in another function what is the best way to store it?

My normal way to deal with this would be pandas but I'm realizing pandas is blocking and is causing issues within my API so I'm trying to bit the bullet and learn the non-pandas way.

Would it just be a dict of dict and then I process each value in parallel?  I apologize if this isn't clear, I'm not sure the data schema's avail to me to use to think about the problem.

Comment: That depends - do you know the payments all up front? You could just put them in a list like `[10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 10, 10]`? And instead of assuming the `year_to_zero` actually go and keep track of the debt and keep going until it is 0 (or below) and check if the payments are actually enough to cover the debt?

Comment: @Grismar Thank you. Would I then have a list of the payments, debt paid, etc and keep all lists the same size then process them based on position?

Comment: That's one way to do it, but a list of dictionaries might make for more readable code, or even a list of lists or tuples of values. You can also ask yourself if you need all those intermediate values at the end of the process, or if you're just interested in a running tally, in which case you can just use single variables. There's no one way to do the job, it depends on what you require from the script.

Comment: @Grismar Thank you so much. I'm going to try that. It's weird, I learned and started to use pandas so much that I just use it everywhere. It doesn't fit all usecases(specifically APIs)